# How to use dictionary update instead of creating list and pass the value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created the code and it's working perfectly fine, but, I want to use dictionary update feature that I have put into the comment in the following code. Need help to understand update feature. I am using JSON data to generate the result. JSON data is at the end of the program. I need to understand the update feature when you are playing multiple dictionaries with lists in it.

Here is my code:

```
from itertools import groupby
def format_account_details(rows):
  result = {}
  total_accounts = 0
  total_account_cost = 0
for k,v in groupby(rows,key=lambda x:x["account_id"]):
    result[k] = {}
    for k2,v2 in groupby(v,key=lambda x:x["business_unit"]):
      result[k][k2] = list(v2)
      for k3 in result[k][k2]:
        total_account_cost = total_account_cost + k3['total_cost']
resp = {}
resp['total_accounts'] = len(result.keys())
resp['total_cost'] = total_account_cost
resp['aggregates'] = []
# resp.update("total_accounts:{}".format(len(result.keys())))
# resp.update("total_cost:{}".format(total_account_cost))
# resp.update("aggregates:{}".format(aggregates))
for k,v in result.items():
  for k2,v2 in v.items():
     resp['aggregates'].append({"account_id":k,
    "business_unit":k2,"top_utilized":v2})
    #merge above two lines by comma (,)    
     for v3 in v2:
       del v3['account_id'], v3['service_name']     
return resp
print(format_account_details(row["aggregates"]))
```

My JSON data:

```
{
"aggregates": [{
    "services_count": 9,
    "service_name": "S3",
    "business_unit": "IT OPS",
    "last_month_costs": 0,
    "total_cost": 0.3200019691,
    "ytd_spends": 0.3200019691,
    "account_id": "136981853693"
}, {
    "services_count": 5,
    "service_name": "RDS",
    "business_unit": "Customer Service",
    "last_month_costs": 0,
    "total_cost": 297.6462777693,
    "ytd_spends": 297.6462777693,
    "account_id": "136981853693"
}, {
    "services_count": 38,
    "service_name": "EBS",
    "business_unit": "IT OPS",
    "last_month_costs": 0,
    "total_cost": 49.7080945265006,
    "ytd_spends": 49.7080945265006,
    "account_id": "136981853693"
}, {
    "services_count": 3,
    "service_name": "ELB",
    "business_unit": "IT OPS",
    "last_month_costs": 0,
    "total_cost": 1.5519276537,
    "ytd_spends": 1.5519276537,
    "account_id": "136981853693"
}, {
    "services_count": 22,
    "service_name": "EC2",
    "business_unit": "IT OPS",
    "last_month_costs": 0,
    "total_cost": 442.70678455851,
    "ytd_spends": 442.70678455851,
    "account_id": "136981853678"
}]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can find [documentation for `dict.update` here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) if you want to understand how to use the method. It's not clear what you mean by "playing multiple dictionaries with lists in it"; can you clarify?

Comment: `update` takes a dict, or an iterable of key-value pairs, not a string representing a key-value pair. If you want to use it, the code would be something like `resp.update({"total_accounts": len(result.keys())})`. But there's no good reason to use `update` instead of `resp["total_account"]=` when you're only updating a single key-value pair.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: @Hamms for example like this : { [ { }, { }, { } ]   [{ }, { }]   { { } }   }